# ssrs dataset shows just 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I need to add a parameter in order to select a range from Monday to Sunday. I made a dataset with the following code

```
DECLARE @W int
SET @W = 0
WHILE @W < 10
BEGIN

  SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE() -7*@W), 0),
    101)                                                      +' - ' + CONVERT(
    VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE()         -7*@W), 6),
    101) Dte,
    CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(WEEK,-1*@W,DATEADD(DAY , 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,
    GETDATE()),GETDATE()))) "Sunday"
   SET @W = @W +1

END
```

And I added a parameter to get available values from this dataset, but It does show just the first row 05/29/2017 - 06/04/2017. What I'm doing wrong and How can I get the 10 rows from the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query returns 10 result sets, and SSRS will only ever use the first. I am going to skip ahead how to correct your query, and go straight to the right way of doing it, you don't need a loop at all. It is fairly straight forward to generate a list of 10 numbers (0-9) in SQL Server using a [table value constructor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382(v=sql.110).aspx):

```
SELECT Number
FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) AS t (Number);
```

With this table of numbers, you can generate your full data set:

```
 SELECT
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE())-7*t.Number, 0), 101) +' - ' + 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, GETDATE())-7*t.Number, 6),101) Dte,
        CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(WEEK,-1*t.Number,DATEADD(DAY , 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()),GETDATE()))) "Sunday"
FROM (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) AS t (Number);
```

If you need more than 10 rows, then there are still much better ways than a loop. See the following series for further reading:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 1](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 2](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 3](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3)